# LM350 as a current supply with Li-ion batteries

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, current-limiting

I am trying to make an circuit to control max current using an [LM350](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm350-n.pdf). The power source is a Li-ion 3.7 V, 2200 mAh battery. I hope to add a maximum current controller and a small push button to turn on the output.

How could I create a constant charge circuit that I can turn on with a push button?

I tried some circuits, but those applications drain the battery in a few pulses and the current is not limited.

Comment: I suspect the LM350 is totally unsuited for what you want reading between the lines. Try stating what you require without guessing a circuit that probably won't work.

Comment: actually i am new to electronics. is there any MOSFET transistor for above requirement?

Comment: You haven't stated your requirements by any stretch of the imagination. Input voltage range, output regulation value (current and voltage), loading, temperature range etc..

Answer (score 1):

You could adapt a circuit like this which uses a linear regulator, this gives an example of how to use a linear regulator to do a constant current.

[image]
Source: http://www.tij.co.jp/product/jp/LM3420/datasheet/application_and_implementation#SNVS1168511

The one problem with this is you need constant current, then constant voltage, and the circuit above at first glance does not appear to be able to do the constant voltage part.

[image]
Source: http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_lithium_ion_batteries

You are better off (and probably cheaper) to buy an charge controller in an IC or on a proto board

Comment: thanks for your comment, i think this is kind of charger. right? i am using Microchips MCP73830 module for charging oprations. so i need a way to use MOSFET as a switch and current limiter. so is there a way to make both of them from single MOSFET component?

Comment: I don't answer questions to people who don't participate in the EE.SE community

Comment: what is EE.SE comunity?